# My animation image is not changing using matplotlib imshow animation

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, imshow

I want to animate going through each Monte-carlo cycle in my code. However, the image is not updating and stays the same as the one started with.

ground_state is a 2D-array that changes after each call to simulate. I have checked that it does get changed in the update

```
fig = pyplot.figure()
im = pyplot.imshow(ground_state, animated = True)

def update_fig(*args):
    global ground_state
    simulate(ground_state, 100000, 2.4)
    im.set_data(ground_state)
    return im

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_fig, interval = 50)

pyplot.show()
```

Here's the simulate function :-

```
def simulate(state, n, T):
    """
    Simulates at temperature T for N iterations.
    """
    def acceptance_ratio(del_E):
        """
        Calculates the acceptance ratio.
        """
        # value of beta = 1 / (boltzmann constant * T)
        beta = 1 / T
        if (del_E) < 0:
            return 1
        else:
            return e ** (-beta * (del_E))

    step = 0
    cycle = 0
    # Single flipping
    for dummy in range(n):
        switch = (random.choice(range(len(state))), 
random.choice(range(len(state))))
        neighbours = nearest_neighbours(switch[0], switch[1], len(state))
        change_E = 0
        for pos in neighbours:
            change_E += 2 * J * state[pos[0]][pos[1]] * state[switch[0][switch[1]]
    p = acceptance_ratio(change_E)
    step += 1
    if step == 100 * 100:
        cycle += 1
    rand_num = random.random()
    if rand_num <= p:
        state[switch[0]][switch[1]] *= -1
    return state
```

Answer (score 0):

We can't know what happens inside of the `simulate` function, but it seems that's the origin of the problem, because else, the code runs fine and animates,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

def simulate(*args):
    global ground_state
    ground_state = np.random.randn(5,5)

simulate()

fig = plt.figure()
im = plt.imshow(ground_state, animated = True)

def update_fig(*args):
    global ground_state
    simulate(ground_state, 100000, 2.4)
    im.set_data(ground_state)
    return im

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_fig, interval = 50)

plt.show()
```

[image: animated image]

Comment: I added the code for the simulate function. It seems to update the array. Anyway, the thing is the 2D-array gets updated. I have checked this thing. I don't understand. Is it possible that the time taken by the function call exceeds the animation time ?

Comment: That is possible. Running a loop over 100000 indices is pretty slow in python.

Comment: I found a very weird anomaly. It runs totally fine if my initial grid is made up of two values. However, when my initial state is uniform that is made up of a single color, it doesn't. It seems that the animation doesn't allow new colors to be introduced while it is running.

Comment: Would you like to normalize the colors in each loop step or use a single normalization?